# How to describe tree model in Realm?

Tags: android, realm, nosql

So I'm curious is it possible to put a model like this:

```
class Parent{
    Parent kid;
}
class Parent{
    Kid kid
}
class Kid{
    //valuable stuff
}
```

`Parent -> Parent -> ... -> Parent -> Kid`. The problem that it can be as much levels as possible of `Parent` classes and only in the end after 3 or 7 passes `Kid` class. Now I'm just going recursively over `JSONObject` and storing one big `JSONObject` but I would love to put model into Realm and not going over it every time. Any suggestion on how to treat such a structure is really welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would model it as a recursive datastructure, e.g.:

```
class Person {
 private Person person;
 private Parent parent;
 private Kid kid;
}
```

and then use appropriate null-checks to determine what kind of Person it is.